# Extracting pixel values by overlaying polygons

Tags: python, numpy, gis, rasterio, data-masking

I am trying to extract pixel values by overlaying polygons. I use a code from Patrick Grey (http://patrickgray.me/open-geo-tutorial/chapter_5_classification.html). When I masked the image with the shape features, I wanted, I got `out_image`. Then the next step would be to remove 0, which totally mess up the array as values are not present according bands.
I tried many different ways as to remove 0 and keep the order of band values according to the class. In `R` I can do it without any problem and when I export the data as `CSV` and train the algorithm everything works fine in a `Python` environment.

How can I extract pixel values and keep the numbers band and class-wise?

```
 X = np.array([], dtype=np.int8).reshape(0,8) # pixels for training
 y = np.array([], dtype=np.string_) # labels for training

with rasterio.open(img_fp) as src:
    band_count = src.count
    for index, geom in enumerate(geoms):
        feature = [mapping(geom)]

# the mask function returns an array of the raster pixels within this feature
out_image, out_transform = mask(src, feature, crop=True) 
# eliminate all the pixels with 0 values for all 8 bands - AKA not actually part of the shapefile
out_image_trimmed = out_image[:,~np.all(out_image == 0, axis=0)]
# eliminate all the pixels with 255 values for all 8 bands - AKA not actually part of the shapefile
out_image_trimmed = out_image_trimmed[:,~np.all(out_image_trimmed == 255, axis=0)]
# reshape the array to [pixel count, bands]
out_image_reshaped = out_image_trimmed.reshape(-1, band_count)
# append the labels to the y array
y = np.append(y,[shapefile["Classname"][index]] * out_image_reshaped.shape[0]) 
# stack the pizels onto the pixel array
X = np.vstack((X,out_image_reshaped))
```

Many thanks for any hints!

Comment: Welcome toSO; question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

Here is to solution. I had to slice up the data band wise then transpose it and stack it by columns. After this step **np.vstack** worked and everything is in order.

```
X = np.array([], dtype=np.int8).reshape(0, 9)  # pixels for training
y = np.array([], dtype=np.int8)  # labels for training

# extract the raster values within the polygon 
with rio.open(sentinal_band_paths[7]) as src:
    band_count = src.count
    for index, geom in enumerate(geoms):
        feature = [mapping(geom)]

        # the mask function returns an array of the raster pixels within this feature
        out_image, out_transform = mask(src, feature, crop=True)
        # eliminate all the pixels with 0 values for all 8 bands - AKA not actually part of the shapefile
        out_image_trimmed = out_image[:, ~np.all(out_image == 0, axis=0)]
        # eliminate all the pixels with 255 values for all 8 bands - AKA not actually part of the shapefile
        out_image_trimmed = out_image_trimmed[:, ~np.all(out_image_trimmed == 255, axis=0)]
        # reshape the array to [pixel count, bands]
        out_image_reshaped = out_image_trimmed.reshape(-1, band_count)
        # reshape the array to [pixel count, bands]
        trial = np.split(out_image_trimmed, 9)  ##### share it to equally after bands
        B1 = trial[0].T  ####transpons columns
        B2 = trial[1].T
        B3 = trial[2].T
        B4 = trial[3].T
        B5 = trial[4].T
        B6 = trial[5].T
        B7 = trial[6].T
        B8 = trial[7].T
        B9 = trial[8].T
        colum_data = np.column_stack((B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9))  ####concatenate data colum wise 
        # append the labels to the y array
        y = np.append(y, [shapefile["id"][index]] * out_image_reshaped.shape[0])
        # stack the pizels onto the pixel array
        X = np.vstack((X, colum_data))
```

Answer (score -1):

eliminate all the pixels with 0 values for all 8 bands - AKA not actually part of the shapefile:

```
out_image_trimmed = out_image[:,~np.all(out_image == 0, axis=0)]
```

eliminate all the pixels with 255 values for all 8 bands - AKA not actually part of the shapefile:

```
out_image_trimmed = out_image_trimmed[:,~np.all(out_image_trimmed == 255, axis=0)]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please take a minute to see how to properly format your code (done it for you now). Also, please do not post external links irrelevant to the answer (removed).